# Quill: how to get html data with the styling included?

Tags: quill

How can I get the html from Quill editor with the css included?

Currently I get the html using `editor.root.innerHTML`. It works, but when I open the html file in browser the styling isn't there. For example I aligned a paragraph to be in center. The result is a paragraph tag with class `ql-align-center` but without the definition of the class itself, so it renders without center alignment in browser.

Is there a method to generate html with the style included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use inline style attributes instead of classes.
This Quill [guide](https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#class-vs-inline) explain how.

```
var ColorClass = Quill.import('attributors/class/color');
var SizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
Quill.register(ColorClass, true);
Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);

// Initialize as you would normally
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: true
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

Comment: thanks, after reading above, I found the import docs https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#import, it says that "In general the path should map exactly to Quill source code directory structure", so I assume it is in `node_modules/quill/` but there isn't a directory called attributors. However, when I use `Quill.import('attributors/style/align')` it works, it returns inline align styling in HTML.

and about the example https://quilljs.com/playground/#class-vs-inline-style the background and color class is still using classes with span tag.

Comment: Quill registers attributors here: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/quill.js#L46

Comment: Color and background attributors use style by default so just delete ColorClass from the example above.

Comment: Could someone please help me with this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479292/how-to-register-alignment-styles-in-react-quill